# How to share local files between two computers using node.js?

Tags: node.js, file, http

I'd like to let another user download a file from my local machine (mac), preferably using `http` protocol. I recently learned about streams in node.js and it seems like an interesting project to set up my server locally and stream some big file to another computer (more than 1 GB). I know how to set up a server but because the files are hosted locally how can I pull this off using node? What would be the prerequisites and steps for such a project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're hosting files on one machine and making them available using Node, I would recommend using [express](http://expressjs.com/), as it is every easy to use.

Using express, hosting files would look something like this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


app.use('/', express.static('./files')); // replace ./files with the path to the directory holding the file/files you want to make available


app.listen(80); // :80 is default http port
```

However if you're looking to use actual streams with Node's native `http` module, give [this a look](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).

Comment: let me know if this answers your question or if I'm not understanding what you're asking :)

Comment: As I mentioned in the OP I know how to set up a server (the part you describe in your answer). However what URL will the other computer have to access? I don't want to host the big files on a third-party server and I can't make them available to the other computer via localhost so how do we connect?

Comment: Sorry the late reply, somehow the notification slipped through my email. You can connect via the host computer's IP on your local network (if you don't know your local IP, you can see how to get it here: https://www.howtogeek.com/117371/how-to-find-your-computers-private-public-ip-addresses/ )

Comment: the part where I connect to someone is what interests me. Can you please elaborate on how do I connect and using what tools? Also I'm not planning to connect to someone over LAN and as far as I know the IP is dynamic usually (mine is) how do I make the connection work when the IP changes?

Comment: @Yos That part I'm not as sure about, you could always make whatever the host device is keep the same local IP (the procedure for doing is different from router to router). Also, you're just going to the local ip in your browser, followed by "/<filename>", so the changing ip (if your local IP's change a lot) won't require a huge amount of work, as there aren't any files to update (assuming you're manually viewing the files from a browser)

Comment: @Yos I really don't want to be that guy, but if I gave you what you were looking for I would really appreciate it if you would mark it as best answer. I'm totally fine if you don't mark it either, let me know what I missed :)

Comment: Thanks so much for marking it as the best answer! If you need anything else feel free to let me know and I'll do my best to help :)